# How do I create set up batch update members via profile?

Tags: profile

I want to expire all members in the database and start over. [image]

Comment: Thanks for your post. It would be helpful if you could provide some more information about what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you start by looking at the documentation on [Profiles](http://gitbook.civicrm.org/organising-your-data/profiles.html).  If you still have questions please come back with some more details about what the problem is.